# Maximize a recursive series where $k \ne 1$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, derivatives, optimization, summation

Is it possible to calculate $df_{n}/dC$ where:

$$
f_n = f_{n-1} + Cp_{n}f_{n-k} \\
$$

I'm trying to calculate f' and f'' so that I can use [Newton Optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method_in_optimization) to calculate C which maximises f.

Let's say $f_{0} = 1$.

k is not a constant and each preceding $f_{n-k}$ is used only once.  $p_n$ are a series of real numbers (positive and negative).

I'm not sure the way I have phrased my question is mathematically correct so please feel free to suggest any edits, however I hope I have gotten across what I'm trying to do.

**What I have done:**

When k = 1 we have:

$$
f_n = f_{n-1} + Cp_{n}f_{n-k} \\
f_n = f_{n-1} + Cp_{n}f_{n-1} \\
f_n = f_{n-1}(1 + Cp_{n}) \\
f_n = \prod_{i=1}^{n} (1 + Cp_{n})
$$

[Maximising the above is equivalent to minimising this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/325454/603358):

$$
g = - log(f_n) = - \sum_{i=1}^{n} log(1 + Cp_{n})
$$

So I can determine g' and g'' and use them in Newton Optimization to calculate a value of C which maximizes f.

But doing something similar when k is not a constant and not equal to 1:

$$
f_n = f_{n-1} + Cp_{n}f_{n-k} \\
f_n = f_{n-1}(1 + Cp_{n}\frac{f_{n-k}}{f_{n-1}}) \\
f_n = \prod_{i=1}^{n} (1 + Cp_{n}\frac{f_{n-k}}{f_{n-1}}) \tag{1}
$$

But we know:
$$
\frac{f_{n-k}}{f_{n-1}} = \prod_{i=n-k}^{n-2} (1 + Cp_{n}\frac{f_{n-k}}{f_{n-1}}) \tag{2}
$$

Should I substitute (2) into (1).  It gets messy because of the recursion and I'm not sure if I'm on the path to nowhere!